# Remove all instances of multiline string from UNIX file

Tags: unix, replace, multiline

I have a large XML file generated from Informatica which has multiple occurrences of Empty XML Tags as given below which needs to be removed from the file.

> ```
>  <Person>
>      <Address>
>      </Address>
>
>
>  </Person>
> ```

The file contains around 600-800 occurrences of the above 6 line text, all of which needs to be removed.

There may be data between those tags, in which case they should not be removed, Removal should happen only when the text appears in the exact same manner as shown above.
PS-perl command doesnt work in my UNIX box

Comment: You don't specify which language/tool you're looking at using, so I'll assume shell or built-in tools. You could do a simplistic line-oriented solution using an awk script. Search for the start tag, set a flag and skip output until you see the end tag. But it would be more robust to do this with an actual XML parser. Have a look at Python - you can get a basic XML parser going quite easily.

Comment: The files are generated by Informatica to a UNIX Server. Looking forward to a UNIX Shell command to clean the file before FTPing the same to report servers. Would not

Comment: The files are generated by Informatica to a UNIX Server. Looking forward to a UNIX Shell command to clean the file before FTPing the same to report servers. Would not be feasible to go for a tool like Python. Also, the lines need to be removed only when there is no data between these tags i.e. they appear as it is. So matching only the start and end string would not resolve the purpose.

Comment: Text processing tools (built in) tend to be line-oriented and not particularly stateful, which is why I suggested awk. Your example shows you need to maintain state across multiple lines and work with an XML document. I suggest Python, which has a great XML parser support, and would be perfectly suited to the task. It is not clear why Python (or Perl which is another great option) is not feasible - it is ported to many architectures, ships with many systems, is well documented and can easily be invoked from a shell as a script. If these aren't options, it is not clear what would be.

Comment: awk is an option we can work with. Any useful links/similar solutions implemented with awk which you can point me to.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is line-oriented, but you can use a state machine to perform multi-line processing.  It's hard to know exactly how it should behave without more schema details and sample data.  But assuming each tag is on its own line, it should be possible.

Following is a simple example of how you might go about solving this (a starting point that you should be able to tailor to your data):

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

BEGIN           { state = 0; }

/<Person>/      { if (state == 0) { print "#Person"; state = 1 } else { state = 0; print } next }

/<Address>/     { if (state == 1) { print "#Addr"; state = 2 } else { state = 0; print } next }

/<\/Address>/   { if (state == 2) { print "#CloseAddr"; state = 3 } else { state = 0; print } next }

/^\s*$/         { if (state == 3) { print "#Blank"; state = 3 } else { state = 0; print } next }

/<\/Person>/    { if (state == 3 || state == 4) { print "#ClosePerson"; state = 0 } else { state = 0; print } next }

{ print } # Default action
```